# In the JFrog Artifactory portal, what are the icons next to the repo names?

Tags: artifactory

[image: JFrog Artifactory repo icons]

I know that they are meant to represent repo type, but there is no key or legend anywhere, not even in the documentation, and Googling comes up empty. I can't even cross-reference with the repo info page, because that page only displays the package type, not the repo type.

I only know of 3 types of Artifactory repos (local, remote, virtual), so I'm confused as to why there are so many icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some sort of a legend when you press on "Repository Types" at the top line of the "Artifacts" view:

[image]

The missing icon belongs to [Build-Info Repository](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-integrations-documentation/build-info-repository).

Read here about [Federated Repositories](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/federated-repositories).